# Xml parser with customization using PHP

Tags: php, html, xml

My xml tag format is

```
<transcript>
<messages>
    <message>
        <to>user1@localhost.local</to>
        <from>user2@localhost.local</from>
        <body>hello</body>
        <date>2014-09-09 14:14:17.652 IST</date>
    </message>
    <message>
        <to>user2@localhost.local</to>
        <from>user1@localhost.local</from>
        <body>hi dear</body>
        <date>2014-09-10 14:14:17.652 IST</date>
    </message>
</messages>
</transcript>
```

I want to load This xml file and display result in format like

```
2014-09-09 - Tuesday
(2:14 PM ) user1 : hello
2014-09-10 - Wednesday
(2:14 PM )user2 : hi dear
```

I have tried this PHP code

```
$xml_file_path='filename_with_path';
$XMLReader->open($xml_file_path);
while ($XMLReader->read() && $XMLReader->name !== "transcript");
while ($XMLReader->read() && $XMLReader->name !== "messages");
while ($XMLReader->read() && $XMLReader->name !== "message");
while ($XMLReader->name === "message") {
    $node = new SimpleXMLElement($XMLReader->readOuterXML());
}
```

but $node give me empty result,How can I fix it or where I am wrong.

Comment: Maybe [`simplexml`](http://ch1.php.net/manual/de/function.simplexml-load-file.php) will make things a lot easier for you.

Answer (score 0):

I personally hate xml, I know it's a mature standard, but I hate working with non-native data stores. Even databases irk me.

If I may refactor your code a bit...

```
//This turns your xml into a php object, which can be manipulated more directly
if (file_exists('text.xml')) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('text.xml');
}
```

then you can output pretty simply

```
$totalMessages = count( $xml->messages->message );
for($i = 0; $i < $totalMessages; $i++){
    echo "{$xml->messages->message[$i]->date}<br>
    {$xml->messages->message[$i]->from}: {$xml->messages->message[$i]->body}<br><br>";
}
```

This outputs

```
2014-09-09 14:14:17.652 IST
user2@localhost.local: hello

2014-09-10 14:14:17.652 IST
user1@localhost.local: hi dear
```

I leave it up to you to slice and dice your strings for prettiness.

Comment: As a side note: If your format is sending oo data to a different program, using json is usually easier. This is because json makes a distinction between objects and arrays and other datatypes. It's built in. That means that a json parser can automatically take in an object whereas working with xml will essentially force you to do some menial work.